# OpenGL ES respecting alpha for background but not for objects

Tags: android, opengl-es, alpha

I have a problem with the alpha of my game, maybe it is solved in another post but as I am new in OpenGl and Game developemnt I dont understand most of the vocabulary and cant find a solution.

The problem is I have enemies with alpha and coins with alpha that works great, but when an enemy pass through the coin it take seem the background instead of the coin(same with shoots)

there is a image explaining it

[image]

There is the code to draw enemys and coins

```
public void drawEnemy(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // Front face in counter-clockwise
                                    // orientation
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // Cull the back face (don't display)

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Enable
                                                            // texture-coords-array
                                                            // (NEW)
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define
                                                            // texture-coords
                                                            // buffer (NEW)

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // front
    switch (type)
    {
        case 0:
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureLoader.textureIDs[0]);
            break;
        case 1:
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureLoader.naveEnemigaIDs[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureLoader.naveEnemigaIDs2[0]);
            break;
    }

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Disable
                                                            // texture-coords-array
                                                            // (NEW)
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
}


public void drawCoin(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // Front face in counter-clockwise
                                    // orientation
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // Cull the back face (don't display)

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Enable
                                                            // texture-coords-array
                                                            // (NEW)
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define
                                                            // texture-coords
                                                            // buffer (NEW)

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // front
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureLoader.CointextureIDs[0]);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Disable
                                                            // texture-coords-array
                                                            // (NEW)
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
}
```

Comment: disable depth testing, or depth write

Comment: or sort your object from back to front

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how I can do that? and why it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the drawing order. If I draw the money and then the ship it respect the alpha.